# get <img> value from a string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm parsing data from a json file. Now, I've a data like this

```html
String Content = <p><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-56999" alt="abdullah" src="http://www.some.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/imageName.jpg" width="348" height="239" />Text</p>
<p>Text</p> <p>Text</p><p>The post <a href="Some URL">Some Text</a> appeared first on <a href="http://www.some.com">Some Webiste</a></p>
```

Now, I want to divide this string in two pieces.  I want to get this URL from `src`.

```
http://www.some.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/imageName.jpg
```

and store it a variable. Also, I want to remove the last line `The Post appeared...` and store the text's in another variable.

So, the questions are:

1. Is it possible to get that?
2. If possible, how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3):

**IN Java**

Get a Document object

```
Document originalDoc = new SAXReader().read(new StringReader("<div>data</div>");
```

Then you can parse it.. (read this tutorial)

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

**In JavaScript**
 to get attribute

```
var url = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src');
```

In case if you have a string and you want a document object, use jquery

```
string stringValue = '<div>data</div>';
var myObject= $(stringValue);
```

Comment: Fast answer and useful +1

Comment: Thanks.But, I am working on Android. How can I use JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `String.substring(firstIndex, lastIndex)` to get the link from `src` attribute
2. learn to use a HTML parser like [`JSoup`](http://jsoup.org/), will be useful in near future

Comment: From the day i have started to use it, i am loving it :)

Answer (score 0):

If its a well structured string you can parse it using any DOM parser and extract data from it...